# Integrability of a complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Given a linear map $J: T \mathbb{R}^4  \to T\mathbb{R}^4$
$$
J= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
f_1 & f_3 & 0 & 1 \\
f_2 & f_4 & -1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Under what conditions on $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^4 \subset C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^4)$ is $J$

- an almost complex structure
- A complex structure

The first question seems okay, multiplying the matrix with itself yields $J^2 = - $id $\iff   f_2 = f_3, f_1 = -f_4$. Now for the integrability condition, I know that an almost complex structure of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0& 0 & -1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
defines a complex structure, but is this a necessary condition for integrability?

Comment: You may the the [Newlander-Nijenberg theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Integrable_almost_complex_structures). that should reduces to a PDE for $f_i$'s.